# How to really make sure that my server has DPDK compatible NIC

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, nic

How to make sure that my server has DPDk compatible NIC ??

I know that I can download dpdk first and then by running ./dpdk-devbind.py from usertools folder can show me the list of NICs using dpdk compatible driver.. But in a brand new server, we haven't installed the dpdk compatible driver and tried binding it to NICs yet, so it's just showing all the NICs using the kernel driver though it has some NICs which are dpdk compatible.

https://core.dpdk.org/supported/ also shows dpdk-supported hardware but let's say a NIC using i40e driver doesn't necessarily mean it supports dpdk? or is it..? there are also so many other hardware that supports dpdk other than these listed here

I can get NIC info from "lshw -c net" command and get info about this from the site, but this seems messy and sometimes unclear.

I just want to know whether there are some simple steps/commands by which I can be 100% sure that my brand new server has DPDK-compatible NICs or not and if so, I want the the names of the interfaces that has dpdk compatible NICs before even trying to install dpdk compatible drivers and binding them to NICs